# Javascript date.valuof() in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I am transcribing some code from Javascript to C# and I am stuck handling a date function.

Lets say my date is 12-Mar-2017 22:00. If I run the following function in js:

```
 date.valueof()
```

I get the primative value of 1492048800000

C# DateTimes do not seem to have a valueof() function that returns a primative from 1970. Any ideas on the simplest way to achieve the same double value in C#

Comment: `double result = (yourDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: My question was downvoted into oblivion. Sorry guys, I know it's really simple for a someone used to working in js. Today was my first day seeing js. C# has spoiled me with its DateTime functions so I was confused as to what valueof() was actually returning. Answers below cleared it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your date, subtract the `1/1/1970` and then get the `TotalMilliseconds`

```
 date.ToUniversalTime()
 .Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
 .TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds.aspx) method.

```
var result = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```